# JMagick Method setGeometry of MontageInfo class crashes JMV

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

Trying to montage multiple images into one. Wortks fine with default geometry. But if i try to set it, JVM crashes.

```
MontageInfo montageInfo1 = new MontageInfo(new ImageInfo());
montageInfo1.setGeometry("+0+0");



#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
##  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x770f5ead, pid=5180, tid=5344
##
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 interpreted mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x55ead]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Lisp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\met7Test\hs_err_pid5180.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to repemphasized textort the bug.
#

#[error occurred during error reporting , id 0xc0000005]

Java Result: -1
```

OS: Windows 7, using JDK 1.6. JMagick v 6.3.9 Q16